# How can I update my subscribe data?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-observable

I have a service that makes some http call to a rest api. On my component I have a subscribe to it. How can I update the data on the subscribe without having to make a new call to the service?

Comment: what value do you want update ? generally inside subscription you will assign your subscribe data to local component variable. you can directly update your local value. post some code ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not quite clear, but I think I can infer enough to hopefully offer an answer.

Let's assume you have an observable of a `User` object that has an `OrganizationId` property on it, and you want an observable of the `Organization` object associated with that `OrganizationId`. You want it to update when the user updates, right?

This is what you would want to use the `flatMap` operator for. Assume our `organizationService` has a `byId$` method that takes in the `OrganizationId` and returns an observable from the `http.post()` method.

```
organization$ = user$
    .flatMap(user => organizationService.byId$(user.OrganizationId));
```

You can think of `flatMap` as similar to `map` in that it will take one value, and turn it into another based on the callback that you pass to it. The difference is that if you used the normal `map` in this way, you would end up with an observable of an observable. `flatMap` will unwrap the observable that is returned to it so you just have an observable of your desired object.